# "Path 'hashed_password' is required" even though hash_password field is full when using virtual field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, validationerror

I am trying to create an app where the password is sent into a virtual field, then hashed and stored as a hash. However I keep getting this error:

```
(node:32101) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: hashed_password: Path `hashed_password` is required.
```

Below is my code and when I run it, I get the logs included below the code.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
const cryptop = require('crypto');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    hashed_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated: Date
});

userSchema
    .virtual("password")
    .set(password => {
        // create temporary variable called _password
        this._password = password;
        // generate a timestamp
        this.salt = uuidv1();
        // encryptPassword()
        this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
        console.log(this);
    })
    .get(function () {
        return this._password;
    });

userSchema.methods = {
    encryptPassword: password => {
        if (!password) return "";
        try {
            return crypto
                .createHmac("sha1", this.salt)
                .update(password)
                .digest("hex");
        } catch (err) {
            return "";
        }
    }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Error:

```
Express is listening on port 8080
DB connected
{ name: 'Ryan', email: 'ryan1@gmail.com', password: 'rrrrr' }
(node:32477) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.encryptPassword is not a function
```

When I do it without the encryptPassword function, I still get an error:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
const cryptop = require('crypto');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    hashed_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated: Date
});

userSchema
    .virtual("password")
    .set(password => {
        // create temporary variable called _password
        this._password = password;
        // generate a timestamp
        this.salt = uuidv1();
        // encryptPassword()
        // this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
        this.hashed_password = 'Test hash';
        console.log(this);
    })
    .get(function () {
        return this._password;
    });

userSchema.methods = {
    encryptPassword: password => {
        if (!password) return "";
        try {
            return crypto
                .createHmac("sha1", this.salt)
                .update(password)
                .digest("hex");
        } catch (err) {
            return "";
        }
    }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Error:

```
Express is listening on port 8080
DB connected
{ name: 'Ryan', email: 'ryan1@gmail.com', password: 'rrrrr' }
{
  _password: 'rrrrr',
  salt: 'ff790ca0-34f0-11ea-9394-a53427d4f6bb',
  hashed_password: 'Test hash'
}
(node:32577) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: hashed_password: Path `hashed_password` is required.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `function(password)` instead of `password =>`.

When you use an arrow function, `this` is not referring to the user you are saving, which is also why you aren’t seeing name and email when you console log it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `password => {...}`, declaring a proper function may help with your issue: `function(password)`.

Also check your `encryptPassword` function the error is most likely coming from there.

Example:

```js
userSchema.methods = {
    // below function will get the plain password 
    encryptPassword: function (password) { 
        if (!password)
            return "";
        return crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt)
            .update(password)
            .digest('hex');
    }
}
```